# Duplicate ajax responses

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, file-upload

When I'm uploading a file I make an AJAX request:

```
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: "../public/currentfile",                   
            dataType: 'json',
            method:'get',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data); 
                var created_at = data['created_at'];
                var filesize = data['filesize'];
                var filename = data['filename'];
                var fileid = data['fileid'];
                $("#results .toBeSelected").prepend("<tr class='tabledata'><td>" + fileid + "</td><td>" + filename + "</td><td>" + filesize + "</td><td>" + created_at + "</td></tr>");
            }                    
        });
    });
```

I get the filesize, filename and so on and pass them to the browser. Everything's ok when I upload a single file. But when I upload more than 5 files at once, some of the responses are duplicate.

What is wrong? Is this a wrong practice?

Comment: I don't get it, how do you upload anything, there's no data sent here from the client at all ?

Comment: There is. I'm just using Laravel and I can't put all the code here. Assume that some files are uploaded. And I prepend their filename and filesize to a table. But when I upload many files at once some of the files in the created table are dublicated although there is no duplicates in the DB or in the filesystem